# Jena, DBpedia: RDF and model name

Tags: java, model, rdf, jena, dbpedia

I'm using dbpedia in my app, and I'm using Jena for the semantic logic.

In Jena, the classes are:

*Model*: a set of statements
http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html
*Resource*: http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html

In dbpedia, the rdf code of a resource is this:
e.g. http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_of_Sweden
becomes http://dbpedia.org/data/Frederick_of_Sweden.rdf

If I call:

```
Model model = maker.createModel( "http://dbpedia.org/data/Frederick_of_Sweden.rdf")
```

A model with the name 'http://dbpedia.org/data/Frederick_of_Sweden.rdf' is created.
But I actually need to call it 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_of_Sweden', to be consistent with the rdf statements. How do I name a model?

If I want to navigate the graph and reach other nodes, which is the best way to store these statements? Do I need a separate model for each dbpedia resource, or can I merge all the statements in one big model?

Thanks for any hint!
Mulone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the way you create your models really affect the way you download the data. You can create your model with the URI identifier that you like.

Here I show an example that can give some ideas of how to separate the way you get your triples from DBPedia and the way you store them in your backend system.

From your question I assume you are using a database backend so my code is targeted to that kind of backend in Jena.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.SimpleSelector;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.db.DBConnection;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelMaker;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class TestJena {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.sql.SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            

        //The database backend initialization.
        DBConnection connection = new DBConnection(MY_DB, USER, PASS, "mysql");
        ModelMaker dbMaker = ModelFactory.createModelRDBMaker(connection);

        //A file manager to get the triples from the DBPedia revolvable URI. 
        FileManager fManager = FileManager.get();
        fManager.addLocatorURL();
        Model linkedDataModel =
              fManager.loadModel("http://dbpedia.org/data/Frederick_of_Sweden.rdf");


        //Now we copy the in-memory model into our DB backend. 
        //When the model is created you can give it the name that you like.
        Model dbModel = 
              dbMaker.createModel("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_of_Sweden");

        dbModel.add(linkedDataModel);

        StmtIterator iter = dbModel.listStatements();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
            System.out.println(stmt);
        }


        linkedDataModel.close();
        dbModel.close();
        connection.close();
}
```

This example prints ...

```
[http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_i_of_sweden, http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_of_Sweden]
[http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_I_%28of_Sweden%29, http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_of_Sweden]
[http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_I,_Landgrave_of_Hesse-Kassel, http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_of_Sweden]
[http://dbpedia.org:8890/data/Frederick_of_Sweden.rdf, http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/primaryTopic, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Frederick_of_Sweden]
(....)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Yes I'm using a db, but I was wondering if it's better to store all of my triples in one big model, or save separate models. I need to run shortest paths algorithms. Any idea?

Comment: It all depends if you need to keep the provenance of your data. So with different models you would know where the data is coming from. I think is generally better to use separate models. Are you using SPARQL, if you use SPARQL you could have different models and in your query it'd be your decision to use or not to the GRAPH names. I might edit the query later to add an example of that technique ;)

Comment: Alright, I see. Can I for example do a shortest path across different models? The other issue I have is that Jena creates a new table for each model, while I'd like to keep one table.

Comment: Yes, in that case I would move the backend to either Jena/TDB or even better to any well stablished triple store such 4store or Virtuoso. At the end of the day if you start managing millions of triples you'll have to do it anyway. Jena with relational DB as backend doesn't scale.